# Can't get my answer to eloquent javascript 4.3 to work properly. Why can't I set "list.rest = list;"

Tags: javascript

```
function arrayToList(array){
  list = {};
  list.rest = null;
  for( var i = array.length -1; i>=0; i--){
    list.value = array[i];
    list.rest= list;
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

Sorry, this is my fisrt post.  Trying to learn Javascript through the book Eloquent Javascript. Above is my answer to exercise 4.3. which askes you to create a function that takes an array and creates a list (a set of nested objects).  The output should be as follows :

// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}

I think I have all the elements there, but it just doesn't seem to like it when I submit "list.rest = list".   Why can't I do this?

The answer in the book is as follows:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}
```

I get the for loop, but I'm not understanding the difference between their answer and my answer in the body of the for.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please describe what the *question* to exercise 4.3 is, or at least what the code is supposed to do. It would also help to be a bit more specific as to what "it just doesn't seem to like it" means (Error messages? Wrong results?)

Comment: `list.rest = list` makes no sense. And each iteration, you are just over writing value, so I doubt that is what they wanted.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are nesting an object inside itself. Javascript does allow for it, but it seems very strange, I can't think of any good reason why you would do that in your function.

Comment: sorry i just edited the answer.  my first post.  thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstoff: There is a very effective way to build this data structure:

```
function arrayToList(a){
    return a.reduceRight(function(o,n){
        return {value:n, rest:o};
    },null);
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (*left to right*)or in this case [Array.prototype.reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (*right to left*) offers a mechanism to *aggregate* values of an array to one value. It does that by applying a function onto each element of the array and carrying its previous result (`o`). This would be the *JS* (*functional*) way to implement this.

Your code produces a *selfreferencing* infinite datastructure. You do in principle:

```
list={value:"10"}
list.rest=list;
```

That is not, what you wanted.
The example in the book does something *similar*

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

But with one *major* difference.
Since *list* is initially set to `null`, the object looks after the first iteration `{value:20, rest: null}`. So there is an *endpoint* defined. In the second and every following step, you reference through a chain of references to this *endpoint* (`rest:list`)

Comment: Hi Thomas,  Thank you for your response...  Still having trouble wrapping my head around the infinite loop.  I was thinking if 'list = {value:"10", rest = null} and list.rest = list; then won't list = {rest :{value :"10" , rest = null}, value:"10"} ?  thanks again

Comment: The problem occurs, because you are overwriting rest=null in the first step with list and do so in every following step. You destroy your endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I think I have a better understanding of it now.  Much appreciated!